# getFragmentManager() cannot resolved on Custom Dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, dialog, fragment

I have a custom DialogBox,

```
public class DialogBoxLogInPop extends DialogBox implements View.OnClickListener {
//...some code...
}
```

On the main activity there is a button, OnClicked on that button a Sign In Dialog Box will pop out. and when the condition is reach, it will prompt the user to a certain fragment.

```
if (username.trim().length() > 0 && password.trim().length() > 0) {
        if (tTable_Contacts.checkifexist(username, password)) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content, mFragment_member).addToBackStack(null).commit();

            dismiss();

        } else {
            ETLoginDialogEmail.setError("Username is not valid.");
            ETLoginDialogPassword.setError("Password is not valid.");

        }
    }
```

My problem is that, the function getFragmentManager() is cannot be resolved.
Can anyone help me how to fix this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does DialogBox extends ?

Comment: Check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36565823/getfragmentmanager-cannot-resolved-on-custom-dialog/36566078#36566078) and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this,

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Comment: please always add explanations to your answers in SO.

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat.yes i agree even its working also i dont know why this will work

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction()
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
            .replace(R.id.content_main, mFragment_member)
            .commit();
```

Comment: please always add explanations to your answers in SO.

Answer (score 0):

Change constructor of `DialogBoxLogInPop` to receive `activity` like this:

```
public class DialogBoxLogInPop extends DialogBox implements View.OnClickListener {

private Activity activity;
public DialogBoxLogInPop(Activity activity){
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

Now create `DialogBoxLogInPop`'s `instance` like this:

From `Activity`:

```
DialogBoxLogInPop dialogBoxLogInPop = new DialogBoxLogInPop(MainActivity.this); //MainActivity is name of your activity
```

From `Fragment`:

```
DialogBoxLogInPop dialogBoxLogInPop = new DialogBoxLogInPop(getActivity());
```

Now call `FragmentManager` like this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getFragmentManager();
```